# compactmap could not cast the number

Tags: json, swift

I am retrieve the account details from my API show to collection view and I need to show my account number on the section header. My JSON look like below

```
  {
    "data": [{
            "TxnIndicator": "Cr",
            "AccountNumber": 345678901112345,
            "MBLTxnCode": "MBLT908",
            "TxnCurrency": "IRR",
            "TransactionAmount": 2000,
            "AccLvlSuddenSurgeValue": "BUS-ST-ACCLVLVALUE-NSTR-001"
        },
        {
            "TxnIndicator": "Cr",
            "AccountNumber": 345696289714492,
            "MBLTxnCode": "MBLT969",
            "TxnCurrency": "KRW",
            "TransactionAmount": 1000,
            "AccLvlSuddenSurgeValue": "BUS-ST-ACCLVLVALUE-NSTR-001"
        },
        {
            "TxnIndicator": "Cr",
            "AccountNumber": 345696289714492,
            "MBLTxnCode": "MBLT943",
            "TxnCurrency": "KRW",
            "TransactionAmount": 30000,
            "AccLvlSuddenSurgeValue": "BUS-ST-ACCLVLVALUE-NSTR-001"
        },
        {
            "TxnIndicator": "Dr",
            "AccountNumber": 263196281214407,
            "MBLTxnCode": "MBLT618",
            "TxnCurrency": "NPR",
            "TransactionAmount": 20000,
            "AccLvlSuddenSurgeValue": "BUS-ST-ACCLVLVALUE-STR-001"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using **compactmap** functions for aligning  headers. I am using below code

```
self.headerArr = strreports.compactMap {$0[Array(self.arrValue[0].keys)[0]]} as! [String]
```

I can't use codable method because all the keys are unknown. we will know only on run time. when i try to above method i will get the error could not cast the number to string.  how to resolve this?

Comment: Since the `Dictionary` is not ordered, using index for accessing the key-value pairs will return randomly. And may I know why the keys in the api are unknown? API must return the same format everyttime just different values right?

Comment: @PGDev yes because that keys are based on user configuration

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the values of AccountNumber if the key changes everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your field `TransactionAmount` is a number and not a string. You cannot cast the number to string.

Without knowing what `strreports` and `self` are, it makes it hard to debug past that.

Try treating it as a string:

```
strreports.compactMap {"\($0[Array(self.arrValue[0].keys)[0]])"}
```

Here's a more general example:

```
let d: [String: Any] = ["X": "A", "Y": 1]
let headerArr = d.compactMap { $0.value } as! [String] // Crash
print(headerArr)
```

vs

```
let d: [String: Any] = ["X": "A", "Y": 1]
let headerArr = d.compactMap { "\($0.value)" } // No Crash
print(headerArr) // ["1", "A"]
```

Comment: How can achieve

Comment: @Ben10 it's unclear how to solve it because it's unknown what `strreports` and `self` are referring to. See my edit

Comment: if i need particular key value how can achieve using compactmap

Comment: @Ben10, I'm not sure - you should ask a new question

Comment: Does that even resolve the query? OP wants an array of AccountNumber. I don't think your answer satisfies that requirement.

Comment: @PGDev, well they marked it as correct and upvoted it. And never mentioned wanting an array of AccountNumber, so no.